# code works on dev PC but not server

Tags: sql

Having a problem with the following code running on server. It works on dev PC. Any help would be appreciated....

```
USE [stringsdb]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_insertPicks]    Script Date: 09/07/2011 15:27:23 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insertPicks]

/* *********************************************
  Name: usp_insertPicks

  Called from       
*/

@userName varchar(50),
@pick nvarchar(50),
@wk varchar(50),
@subDate datetime

    AS  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   

     DECLARE @sql varchar(max);
--   DECLARE @submitDate1 DATETIME;
--   SET @submitDate1 = GETDATE()

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [tblPicks] ([userName], [pick], [wk], [subDate]) 
        VALUES (@userName,@pick,@wk,@subDate);
    END

    print (@sql) 
    EXECUTE(@sql); 
    SET @sql = '' 

    RETURN
GO
```

I can authenticate against the DB with ASP Membership and other queries work.

The problem was solved with an update to the connection string that was declared in the code behind.

Comment: What is the `EXECUTE(@sql);` stuff all about? That never seems to be assigned any value.

Comment: I have all the necessary rights. The code was actualy generated (in part) by the ASP web publishing wizard.

Comment: The only error is the typical web config can not show full details on the server, but details might be veiwable on the locel machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that you have a database named [stringsdb] on the server.

Verify that you have permission to execute this procedure on the server.

If you're running a select on [tblPicks] to verify that the procedure worked, then verify that you have select permission on that table.

Comment: It was a connection string issue, seems obvious once reading over my question, two different machines, what's different between them. Can't believe the questions caught so much flak!!    Thanks Kuru, you got me looking in the right places.